# I am getting HttpContext.Current equal to null in async method in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous, async-await, httpcontext

I am getting HttpContext.Current null in async method in ASP.NET MVC.

I have tried below things:

1. Created properties and assign through constructor
2. HttpContext current value direct assign to session variable

Still having same issue.

Can anyone help with some sample code to manage those things from async method ?

Comment: Where are you getting this, in a controller, in a middleware, or where?

Comment: I am having below scenario 

I am having static class, from there i am calling static method to send email functionality which i am calling from controller 

In controller i have used async and from there i have called static method for send email.

Comment: Can't you pass the context from the controller to the static method, as a parameter?